# Google App Engine/ Google Cloud SQL - Detect if it is MySQL or Google Cloud SQL

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have this method to create my connection:

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new AppEngineDriver());
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:google:rdbms://" + instanceName + "/myDB");
```

I need to detect if i am using MySQL or Google Cloud SQL.
Because you can pick it in you local test version:

[image: pick]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way using this condition:

```
//this is MySQL
(connection.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName().compareTo("Google SQL Service/MySQL") == 0)
```

Comment: connection.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName().startsWith("Google") should be sufficient (and less brittle).